# help with cakephp foreign keys

Tags: php, cakephp

i'm currently building a calendar which displays events each event belongsto an eventlocation with a foreign key of event_location_id each eventlocation hasmany events with a foreign id of event_location_id. Which gets the name of the event_location based on its id. Now im adding side deals and i can only get the event_location_id and not the name can anyone help? or possibly give a better explanation of what foreign id are for and do.

i just need to know how to get an event by it's id and then get the event_location_id  from the event and then get the name from event_locations table according to the event_location_id.

Comment: it would be nice if you could use some punctuation and also show your code so we can help you better

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the [containable behaviour](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1323/Containable). It will manage the recursion for you. Containable will be good enough for most purposes, unless the query is very complicated.

Answer (score 0):

If you have [set up your associations properly](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1039/Associations-Linking-Models-Together) it should be as easy as:

```
$this->Event->recursive = 2;
$event = $this->Event->read(null, $id);

debug($event);
```

Cake automatically fetches data for associated models.

Comment: @josh It tells Cake how many layers of associations to fetch, and in fact you probably don't even need it. I suggest you study the manual: http://book.cakephp.org/view/1063/recursive